# ListView inside another ListView is not assembling the correct template

Tags: c, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview inside another listview, but the second listview is not respecting the automatic height, apparently it is based on some property of the parent listview as the image.

[Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6jAM.png)

-First listview, I'm using a templateselector of QuestoesTemplates

```
<ListView  x:Name="ListView_ListaPerguntas" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Perguntas}"
                                   SeparatorColor="Black"
                                   HasUnevenRows="True"
                                   SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                                   ItemTapped="ListView_ListaPerguntas_ItemTapped"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource QuestoesTemplates}"
                                   IsEnabled="True">
                        </ListView>
```

-secont listView in of template selector

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MultiplaTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <FlexLayout Direction="Column"  Margin="0,10" BackgroundColor="DarkOrchid">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Ds_DescricaoPergunta}"/>

                    <ListView x:Name="ListView_AlternativaSelecao"
                              HasUnevenRows="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Alternativas}"
                              BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="20"
                              VerticalOptions="Fill">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <FlexLayout Direction="Row">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Ds_DescricaoPergunta}" Margin="10,0"/>
                                        <Label Text=" - "/>
                                        <CheckBox />
                                    </FlexLayout>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Header>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Confirma as alternativas?" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Button Text="Confirmar" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ListView.Header>
                        <ListView.Footer>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Confirma as alternativas?" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Button Text="Confirmar" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ListView.Footer>
                    </ListView>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Confirma as alternativas?" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="Confirmar" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                </FlexLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and the result is the image, he occupying a higher height.

Comment: nesting listviews is a horrible practice and you should really avoid it

Comment: would you have any alternative alternatives to my problem? and what would be a good practice in this case? I have a list of questions, and each question has several alternatives.

Comment: either use a Grouped ListView, or redesign your UI.  You appear to be display a list of questions, where each question has a list of possible answers.  I would break up each question onto a separate page instead of displaying a huge list of questions and answers the user needs to scroll through on a mobile device.

Comment: for example a button to go to the next question, and draw each question on the screen with its alternatives?

Comment: yes, use a LIstView to display the answers for one question, and when they select one (or press a button) navigate to the next question

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired functionality, I would break up each questions into pages, or you can use a horizontal scrolling carousel view. You could even have a button to submit answer and go to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, you could use a Grouped ListView. I make a simple code for you reference.

Xaml:

```
 <ListView IsGroupingEnabled="true" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAnswers}">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Questions}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Ds_DescricaoPergunta}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<AnswerList> _listOfAnswers;
    public List<AnswerList> ListOfAnswers { get { return _listOfAnswers; } set { _listOfAnswers = value; base.OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var Q1List = new AnswerList()
        {
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer1"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer2"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer3"},
        };
        Q1List.Questions = "Q1";

        var Q2List = new AnswerList()
        {
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer1"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer2"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer3"},
        };
        Q2List.Questions = "Q2";

        var Q3List = new AnswerList()
        {
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q3_Answer1"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q3_Answer2"},

        };
        Q3List.Questions = "Q3";

        var Q4List = new AnswerList()
        {
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer1"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer2"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer3"},
            new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer4"},
        };
        Q1List.Questions = "Q4";

        var list = new List<AnswerList> { Q1List, Q2List, Q3List, Q4List };
        ListOfAnswers = list;

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class Answer
{
    public string Ds_DescricaoPergunta { get; set; }
}
public class AnswerList : List<Answer>
{
    public string Questions { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers => this;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is it mandatory for me to inherit a list? Can't I just have a list property in the parent class?

Comment: i'm trying to do without needing to inherit, just having a property but it doesn't work ..

`public class ModelPergunta{
    public string DescricaoPergunta { get; set; }
    public List<Alternativa> Alternativas {get; set;}
}

public class Alternativa
    {
        public string DescricaoAlternativa { get; set; }
    }
`

Comment: If you want a Grouped Listview, it needs to inherit.